# Remove Gaps between Bootstrap div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am having a problem whit gaps between mine two jumbotron's and mine footer.

[Bootpyl](http://www.bootply.com/OxXvkFOfLv) example off mine work.

You can see that between `<div id="paper" class="jumbotron">` and `<div id="form" class="jumbotron">` is a small gap and the same problem is between `<div id="form" class="jumbotron">` and `<footer></footer>`.

It is like `<div id="form" class="jumbotron">` is smaller or something else is going one here that I can figure out.

Can someone explain to me what is happening, thank you.

Comment: You need to override `margin-bottom` from the `.jumbotron` class.

Comment: and you have a <hr> tag before <footer>

Comment: @ShaunakD, thank you I have just solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it as @ShaunakD, suggested by overriding `.jumbotron` `margin-bootom` class and making it `margin-bottom: auto;`.

Now mine CSS code look's like this:

```
#paper {
    background-image: url(../img/paper/paper.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: auto; 
}
```